# Select object menu

Tags: selection-tools

I'm using Blender 2.78c and I read about some useful tips, like the `Select object menu` with the shortcut `ALT + right mouse button`. This is very useful when there are a lot of objects in the scene, but since I have changed to left mouse button to select objects, I wonder if there are any alternative to use the `Select object menu` ?

( I also tested to change back to right mouse button for selection in the user preferences, but I can't get any `Select object menu` that way either )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select object menu works with left select enabled, but it is <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>. It doesn't specifically use the <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>, it is set to use the select mouse button which changes to match the left/right "Select With" option.

As you are adjusting the input preferences and finding it not working, I expect you are seeing the finicky way that input works. If the preferences window is active and you press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> and then click in the 3d view which is another window behind the preferences, it won't work. You need to activate the window with the 3dview, then press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> and then click to get the menu. It is the active window that gets the keydown event, as you then activate the background window while the key is down it doesn't get a new keydown event to know that it is being held.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work! If I click on the background in the 3D-view it's active. Then I press ALT-key and left mouse botton, but no menu appears! Any other ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: It doesn't just "show" anywhere, you need to have multiple items overlapping under the cursor in the 3dview where you alt-click. If there is only one object to select there is no choice to offer.

Comment: OK! I got it! It's working now when I press ALT-key and click on left mouse button on the overlapping objects. I didn't know that I had to click on the objects, I thought it was enough to just click somewhere beside the objects. Thansk for the help!